# AnyLogic: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to move an agent to a point

Tags: gis, agent, anylogic

I'm trying to move an agent using "moveTo"-function to a defined Point on a GIS-map. It works for a couple of Points and then all of a sudden the attached error occurs. Does it mean that the Point is not defined or that AnyLogic can't find a route using the OnlineRouteProvider or does it mean something else?

```
Ausnahme während der Ausführung eines diskreten Ereignisses:
739
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 739
    at com.anylogic.engine.gis.AnyLogicOnlineRouteProvider.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gis.AbstractGISRouteProvider.getPathData(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gis.IGISRouteProvider.getPathData(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gis.AbstractGISRouteProvider.getPathData(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.g.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.g.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.dh.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.dh.moveToInTime(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.dh.moveTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.moveTo(Unknown Source)
    at crowdsouring.Truck.enterState(Truck.java:696)
    at crowdsouring.Truck.executeActionOf(Truck.java:794)
    at com.anylogic.engine.TransitionTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.u(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$i.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the point isn't there, even though that anylogic think it is.
If you have an array of size 4 and try to get something at the 13th place, you'll get this error.

But why this happens depends on the code that initialize the array and the code that determines the possible destination. Do you do it your self or is it an anylogic object that handles it?